# Number formatting

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, formatting

I am attempting to create a C# wrapper for a C class library the controls an USB data bus communication device.  This device supports being hooked up to an external clock or using its own internal clock depending on the value set when the device is initialized.

The manufacture provided header files for its C Library with the following #define variables

```
#define DATA_SRC_INT = 0x000000000L
#define DATA_SRC_EXT = 0x000000001L
#define DATA_SRC_NONE = 0x00000000FL
```

So that leaves me with the question.  What number does `0x000000000L` represent exactly?

I realize that this question might simplistic.  At the time I originally wrote this question I had not seen a great deal of portable C code.  I have attempted based on some feedback I received to clarify my original question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are `long` values of 0, 1 and 15, respectively. The suffixed `L` signals that it is a `long` literal, while the prefix `0x` is for hexadecimal numeric literals.

In C# you can do pretty much the same as well (the `L` suffix isn't necessary here since the compiler already knows the type and converts accordingly – in your C code the defines are only string replacements and therefore the type has to be carried with them):

```
public const long DATA_SRC_INT = 0x0;
public const long DATA_SRC_EXT = 0x1;
public const long DATA_SRC_NONE = 0xF;
```

But unless the hexadecimal notation yields actual insights (such as composition of bit fields) I usually stick to decimals:

```
public const long DATA_SRC_INT = 0;
public const long DATA_SRC_EXT = 1;
public const long DATA_SRC_NONE = 15;
```

Comment: Ramhound: The format is just there for the compiler. If you declare it as `long` in C# as well you shouldn't get any surprises – it's the same type and value after all. The `L` and the hexadecimal notation simply vanishes after the compiler nibbled away at the source. Then again, for a port consistency with the original code is probably not a bad idea either, but the hardware really doesn't care :-)

Answer (score 3):

The 0x means that the number is in hex. The L at the end means that it's a long.

So... the the numbers listed are 0, 1, and 15, respectively.